# Google Scholar error

Tags: google-scholar

I'm filling in my profile in Google Scholar.
In the 2nd step, I should select the articles that I wrote,
but it won't go to the 2nd page (by clicking '>' to see the 2nd page of the articles list)
It happens both at the desktop and mobile phone. 
What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not seem to be replicated as of 2022.
Does this still happen? (I know five years have passed..)